# why do we need to run shutdown.bat for tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat6, shutdown

i start tomcat by running startup.bat and there will be a small cmd-window running the tomcat.
After that i wanted to stop tomcat and I close that window.

And topcat stopped.
so what is the point of shutdown.bat?

Comment: pulling the power plug off your computer and shutting it down ain't same, are they?

Comment: @Pacerier hah, I find it really amusing that you didn't get my question. I was merely remarking upon the fact that closing the console window is just akin to killing the server process whatsoever and that you should always stop it by invoking the shutdown script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most applications can be shutdown in more than one way; there's the "graceful" way, where a program can clean up after itself; the less-than graceful way, where a program can try to catch a shutdown (termination) signal; and the harsh way, where a program is "killed" (kill -9 in unix).  Closing the window is probably closer to the second way.

And of course it wouldn't work very well if you didn't have access to a windowing environment on a remote server.

Answer (score 5):

`shutdown.bat` allows Tomcat to clean up after itself, if it needs to. The functionality to shutdown from a command instead of just closing a window also allows for remote management.